# Data is not updating in production mode in next js 13.5+

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

Actually, Iam working with next js 13.5+, after deployment in Versel, the fresh data is not being called, I saw other questions that are asked by others in Stack overflow, they're using `fetch` method and not `axios` method in next js. Iam using axios method like this:

```
 const [data, setData] = useState<any>();
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("/api/admin/getAllCategories").then((res) => setData(res.data));
  }, []);
```

please tell me the solution of this, the data not being updated using useEffect and axios library.

I cannot switch to `fetch` method because i used this `axios` method in almost every file im my directory. any solutions with this `axios` method and not `fetch` method?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this with fetch.

in home.js

```
const sleep = (ms) => {
      return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
    }    
    const fetchData = async () => {
          const res = await fetch('http://localhost:adress/api/admin/getAllCategories')
          return res.json()
        }
    const Home = async () => {
      await sleep(3000)
      const data= await fetchData()
      console.log(data)
      return (
        <div>
          
        </div>
      )
    }
    export default Home
```

If you are not doing it as a 'use client' and you are using the nextjs app router, you cannot use useeffect and use state. Please let me know if this approach solves your problem

Comment: Actually, i'm using axios method for about more than 50+ files. so i can't roll back to fetch method. any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

```
const getCategories = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(http://localhost:adress/api/admin/getAllCategories');
        return response;
};
const Home = async () => {
      const data = (await getCetegories()
            .then(response => {
                return response
            })
            .catch(error => {
            }))

      console.log(data)

      return (
        <div>
          
        </div>
      )
    }
    export default Home
```

I haven't tested it but this should work.